# duktape exposing a c++ object (methods + properties)

Tags: javascript, c++, duktape

I'm trying to export my objects to javascript but I still don't get how to bind a property "getter" and "setter". a.g:

```
class MyObjectWrapper : public MyObject
{
public:
   void MethodToBind() { ... };

   void PropertySetter(String& s) { Property = s; }
   String& PropertyGetter() { return Property; }
private:
   String Property;
};
```

As my engine manipulates the object property externally I shouldn't set it as a "constant" I guess. I'd like to bind those 2 methods as the setter and the getter so that when a script like above is executed it will call those methods:

```
object.Method(); // call MethodToBind
object.Property = "Hello World!"; // call PropertySetter
printf(Object.Property + '\n'); // call PropertyGetter
```

Is this possible through duktape? Do I have to update the value in the javascript heap every time my engine will change the property value externally from c++ code?

Answer (score 4):

The Duktape/C functions generally have a prototype of

```
int my_func(duk_context *)
```

so I think what you should do is keep the functions you have defined to access your object from C++ (MethodToBind, PropertySetter/Getter) and add private methods

```
...
private:
    String Property;
    int duk_method(duk_context *ctx);
    int duk_setter(duk_context *ctx);
    int duk_getter(duk_context *ctx);
};
```

and implement them as (sorry if there is some details missing, I am not a C++ guy)

```
int MyObjectWrapper::duk_method(duk_context *ctx) {
    MethodToBind();
    return 0; //no args and no return value, no need to act on JS stack
}

int MyObjectWrapper::duk_setter(duk_context *ctx) {
    Property = new String(duk_get_string(ctx, 0)); //first arg to String
    return 0;
}

int MyObjectWrapper::duk_getter(duk_context *ctx) {
    duk_push_string(ctx, Property.c_str());
    return 1; //we pushed one return value
}
```

Now, if you have an object on the duktape JS value stack top that you want to turn into a MyObject, you call

```
duk_push_string(ctx, "Property");
duk_push_c_function(ctx, MyObjectWrapper::duk_getter, 0 /*nargs*/);
duk_push_c_function(ctx, MyObjectWrapper::duk_setter, 1 /*nargs*/);
duk_def_prop(cx, -4, DUK_DEFPROP_HAVE_GETTER|DUK_DEFPROP_HAVE_SETTER);
duk_push_c_function(ctx, MyObjectWrapper::duk_method, 0 /*nargs*/);
duk_put_prop_string(ctx, -2, "Method");
```

If you want JS code to be able to create such an object with

```
my_object = new MyObject();
```

you need to do the above in a native constructor as described here:
https://github.com/svaarala/duktape-wiki/blob/master/HowtoNativeConstructor.md